# Create custom taxonomy for WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have 4 types of products for sale that are completely separate from each other

1. product physical
2. product virtual ( theme and plugin )
3. product virtual ( online video courses )
4. product virtual ( services )

I want each of the products to have their own pages like below :

1. exmaple.com/physical/
2. exmaple.com/website/
3. exmaple.com/courses/
4. exmaple.com/services/

And each has its own product category as below :

1. exmaple.com/physical/category/
2. exmaple.com/website/category/
3. exmaple.com/courses/category/
4. exmaple.com/services/category/

And I want it to look like this when I enter the product page :

1. exmaple.com/physical/product-name
2. exmaple.com/website/product-name
3. exmaple.com/courses/product-name
4. exmaple.com/services/product-name

I use the [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) plugin, I made a taxonomy example for #4, The code below :

```
   function cptui_register_my_taxes_ser() {
    
        /**
         * Taxonomy: services.
         */
    
        $labels = [
            "name" => esc_html__( "services", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
            "singular_name" => esc_html__( "services", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
        ];
    
        
        $args = [
            "label

" => esc_html__( "services", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "query_var" => true,
        "rewrite" => [ 'slug' => 'ser/category', 'with_front' => false,  'hierarchical' => true, ],
        "show_admin_column" => false,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "show_tagcloud" => false,
        "rest_base" => "ser",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Terms_Controller",
        "rest_namespace" => "wp/v2",
        "show_in_quick_edit" => false,
        "sort" => false,
        "show_in_graphql" => false,
    ];
    register_taxonomy( "ser", [ "product" ], $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_taxes_ser' );
```

But there are several questions :

1. Is it possible to create an archive page for `/ser/` and `/ser/category/` page?
2. When I click on the article created in ser taxonomy, the address is as follows : `example.com/shop/product-name` | I want when I click on the text of each taxonomy, the structure should be as I gave in the description above, that is : `example.com/['taxonomy']/product-name`

I kiss your hand in advance for your help.

Comment: What is the difference between `exmaple.com/physical/` and `exmaple.com/physical/product-name` pages?

Comment: `exmaple.com/physical/` is archive physical or home page physical | `exmaple.com/physical/product-name` is single page product physical.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it is possible.
2. This could be possible, but will be a burden to create: would need to add custom rewrite rules for every product taxonomy term, instructing WordPress that it should look for a product and not a page.