# Create some custom typed posts like WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an idea in my head, but I don't know if it can be implemented with WordPress or not?

My site activity includes 4 types :

1. product physical
2. product virtual ( theme and plugin )
3. product virtual ( online video courses )
4. product virtual ( services )

All 4 types of activities must be registered through WooCommerce, I want 4 types of activities to have such a structure :

1. example.com/physical/[archive] | example.com/physical/[category] |
   example.com/physical/[single page product physical]
2. example.com/website/[archive] | example.com/website/[category] |
   example.com/website/[single page product website]
3. example.com/courses/[archive] | example.com/courses/[category] |
   example.com/courses/[single page product courses]
4. example.com/services/[archive] | example.com/services/[category] |
   example.com/services/[single page product services]

In fact, I want to have 4 types of custom post types that all support WooCommerce custom post types, In other words, it is like installing 4 WooCommerce on one WordPress.

[I wanted to achieve this by creating 4 taxonomy for WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76415897/create-custom-taxonomy-for-woocommerce), [But I realized that it is not possible to create an archive page for taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/352295/217265) : example.com/physical/[archive] 404

**Is there a way to implement this idea?**

Comment: There is huge difference between product types and post types :)  Based on your url examples you want custom post types. This part i dont understand what you mean by that " support WooCommerce custom post types". And yes you can implement the idea. Since there can be many considerations may not be the best approach but that came up as idea to be quick - Create custom taxonomy that can support both product and your custom post type . Inside create term that will bind your product to both post types. Then in the archive just tweek it to grab all products from that taxonomy in your CPT archive.

Comment: This is also called relationship method so you can google more about this method since there are many different approaches to create relationship